# Why will the permission argument affect the content written to file in my small test program?

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int rc = fork();

    // if I uncomment this line, the output file's is "testtest" when program exits.
    // int file = open("./output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    // Use this line, the output file contains the string "TESTTEST".
    int file = open("./output", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        write(file, "testtest", 8);
        close(file);
    } else {
        write(file, "TESTTEST", 8);
        close(file);
        int wc = waitpid(rc, NULL, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a small program to practise Linux API, then I encountered a question that I can't understand.

When I pass permission arguments, I can only write content in child process. But when I switch to another open function, I can only write content in parent process.

Could someone help to explain why? Can I get both "TESTEST" and "testtest" in output file ?

Comment: You have a race condition. Whether the parent or the child wins the race is not specified, and probably random.

Comment: What is a "permission argument" for you?

Comment: S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR

Comment: Wrong duplicate actually.

Comment: `O_CREAT` requires you to pass a third argument to `open`.

Answer (score -1):

Because, Every process has a per process file table, When a process opens a file, it creates a new entry for that opened file in file table. This entry contains some information about the file including current position of the cursor in that file. Initially this cursor points to first byte of the file. When a new child process got created, it duplicates the file table of it's parent.

In your case both parent process and child process have a file table entry for file "output", and both will point to the initial byte of that file. If parent writes first (it depends on the scheduling) it will write "TESTTEST" on the file and move the cursor in it's file table to 8 positions front. But cursor of child's file table still points on the initial byte of the same file. and it replaces the parent's written data with "testtest". If child writes first, then the same thing will happen in reverse order - "testtest" will get replaced with "TESTTEST".